# good Oauth2 flow in mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, oauth-2.0

Is a good Oauth2 flow in mobile app ?

Client Credentials When User Access Public Data From My Server With My Mobile App:

Step 1 : Client Send client_id & client_secret ( I include a client_id & client_secret in the app code/package ) To Server , APP Id & App Device ID.

Step 2 : Server Response Access Token & Expired Long Time.

Step 3 : If Access Token Expired Client Request Again Access Token Like Step 1.

Step 4 : If Client Request Data Server Will Check Access Token , APP Id & App Device ID.

Comment: check this https://github.com/AliAbozaid/OAuth2Library

Answer (score 4):

If you plan to use OAuth in your iOS app, I recommend you [Hermod](https://github.com/mobilejazz/Hermod), an HTTP client built on top of AFNetworking (the most popular HTTP client in iOS).

Hermod has a very nice public interface and supports OAuth 2.0 sessions and token management out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some confusion around the usage of the word "client".

In Oauth 2.0 terminology, a client is a piece of software accessing an API. It does not say whether that piece of software is running on a mobile device, or a server.

The OAuth Client Credentials Grant is meant to be used only from a server. Never embed a client secret in an app package that you distribute. The grant type you want is probably the Authorization Code Grant.

I suggest you read the [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

That being said, if the data accessed by the application is public, why do you requiring authorization?